# GridView_RowUpdating with a list C#,

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm very new in asp/c# and I'm trying to make a rowupdating but I can't. I don't know why it just does not work but maybe is because it use a list not a database (I dont know if it is the problem) this is the code I have:

Page load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListOne = new List<Empl>();
        ListOne.Add(new Empl("0000", "Name", "lastname"));
        ViewState["Listado"] = ListOne;
    }
    else
    {
        ListOne = ((List<Empl>)(ViewState["Listado"]));
    }

    PersonasGridView.DataSource = ListOne;
    PersonasGridView.DataBind();
```

And this is the rowupdating:

```
 protected void EmplGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = EmplGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0]);
    String str = txtBox.Text;
    busqResult.Text = str;//I just put this to know if I'm getting a value, but it is empty

    PersonasGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    PersonasGridView.DataSource = ListOne;
    PersonasGridView.DataBind();
}
```

I think the problem is related with the list, or maybe I'm not getting the values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to keep the Binding in `!Ispostback`

Comment: I did try but it does no work, thanks

Comment: try to remove `else` part and add only the databind in `!ispostback`.Did you tried like this only?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a problem with your viewstate. Your listone could be inicialize only once in pageload event. If you try to update row you probably put empty data. Check in debugger what is ListOne in EmplGridView_RowUpdating method if it is empty you must add your data to listone in other place.  For example, before databin rowupdating method, outside IsPostBack block or in OnEveryLoad method (or something similar).